# Check it is the last result for an ID

Tags: codeigniter

I have a forum-like site, which allows users to post. I want users to be able to delete their post ONLY if it is the last for this topic:

Posts Table

```
+--+-------+------+------+------+--------+
|id|content|author|posted|edited|question|
+--+-------+------+------+------+--------+
```

How to check is this post is the last post on this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This for select max id:

```
SELECT MAX( id ) FROM tablename
```

and for select the id of the last post of an author:

```
SELECT MAX(id) WHERE author='something'
```